# How to get the selected row when I click on this row?

Tags: jtable

Hi I need to know which method to use on which event, I want to get the selected row when I click on this row, and lets say this JTable contains 3 columns, if I get the selected row, how can I access the data in its 3 cells?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event to use is JTable table.getSelectedRow() which returns an int type of index of the selected row. You can make a statement such as:

```
 int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
 int value# = table.getValueAt(selectedRow, column #);
```